# ActionScript - same opcode for two distinct instructions?

Tags: actionscript, instructions

Looking at the AVM2 specs ([here](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/actionscript/articles/avm2overview.pdf), page 66-67) i found out that there are two instructions which do something different but they have the same opcode:

greaterequals, 0xAF
greaterthan, 0xAF

Both have the same format (no arguments). Both have the same stack transition. Since these instructions do something different i am a bit confused. Does someone know what are the correct opcodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

greaterequals opcode is 0xb0
In the [online documentation](http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/AVM2/greaterequals) the error is partially fixed (decimal value is wrong still)